# Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp64\www\

Tags: php, while-loop

> Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp64\www....

I hope my loop is not infinite.

```
if(isset($_POST['del']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $st = "Y";
            $stmtp = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE BRN = :inv ORDER BY Sr ASC ');
    $stmtp->bindParam(':inv',$id);
    $stmtp->execute();
    $rowcd = $stmtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    if($stmtp->rowCount() > 0)
    {
    while($rowcd)
        {
            extract($rowcd);
        $stmtd = $user_home->runQuery('UPDATE invoice 
                                         SET State=:uname                                            
                                       WHERE Sr = :crn');
            $stmtd->bindParam(':crn',$Sr);
            $stmtd->bindParam(':uname',$st);
            $stmtd->execute();
        }
    }
    }
```

Select statement has 5 rows. (sometime it may have less)

Comment: How many rows have that SELECT statement?

Comment: @LordNeo Select statement has 5 rows. (sometime it may have less)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an infinite loop.

You're doing:

```
$rowcd = $stmtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and then evaluating it:

```
while($rowcd)
```

When it should be:

```
while($rowcd = $stmtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Instead of both lines

Comment: Thank you so much both answers gave me the solution!

Answer (score 1):

From your usage of `bindParam()`, I'm assuming you're using PDO that you've abstracted into a class.

You're only calling the `fetch()` once which returns a single row, then using a while statement on that. That never gets updated in the loop, so it always evaluates to `TRUE`, thus continuing the loop.

To test this theory, you can run a simple loop on an array, which runs until a break point:

```
<?php
while(array(1,2,3)){
    echo date('H:i:s');
}
```

I'm not entirely sure where the `$Sr` variable is coming from, but based on the `ORDER BY` clause in your first query, it's returned in the first query.

Therefore, you need to loop through and fetch the next row each time like so:

```
...
while ($row = $stmtp->fetch()) {
    $stmtd = $user_home->runQuery('UPDATE invoice 
                                         SET State=:uname                                            
                                       WHERE Sr = :crn');
    $stmtd->bindParam(':crn',$row['Sr']);
    $stmtd->bindParam(':uname',$st);
    $stmtd->execute();
}
...
```

Comment: It is leaving the first query and updating from the second and on...\

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Assume there are 3 rows when the loop starts, queries are updated from 2nd row leaving the first row as it is.

Comment: We don't know the table structure to be able to investigate further, but ultimately, that seems like it may be a different question or issue. Is the while loop not working as it should? (I don't mean the internal update query, but the number of times it loops)